# jQuery BlockUI with Click overlay NOT mobile friendly

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, overlay, jquery-blockui

I'm using jQuery BlockUI Plugin, and it pops up an image over the homepage. I want to be able to click outside of the image anywhere and be able to close it on smart phones. 
I set this code, and it only works on Desktop, but NOT on Mobile:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#demo9').click(function() { 
        $.blockUI(); 
        $('.blockOverlay').attr('title','Click to unblock').click($.unblockUI); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try binding the event with .on() in case there is a timing issue where the overlay does not exist yet:

```
$(".blockOverlay").on("click", function(){ $.unblockUI });
```

or

```
$(document).on("click", ".blockOverlay", function(){ $.unblockUI });
```

Also, does it make any difference if you use vclick instead of click?

Answer (score 0):

Using touchstart with click works on Iphone, Kindle, Ipad

$('.blockOverlay').attr('title','Click to unblock').on('click touchstart',$.unblockUI);